# Why does pygame.mixer.init not change the sampling rate?

Tags: python, pygame, mixer

If I run

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16,2,2048)
pygame.init()
print pygame.mixer.get_init()
```

or

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)
print pygame.mixer.get_init()
```

or

```
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16,2,2048)
print pygame.mixer.get_init()
```

The result is:
(22050, -16, 2)

instead of  (44100, -16,2)

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that, `pygame.init()` initialises the `mixer` module with the default value, which is `(22050, -16, 2)`, unless a `pre_init()` is found.

And the first and third pieces of code work for me, and give an output, `(44100, -16,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the values given to `pygame.mixer.init()` are 'sticky' even if one calls `init()` again. Calling `pygame.mixer.quit()` before `pygame.mixer.init()` again makes it work for me:

```
>>> import pygame
>>> pygame.mixer.init()
>>> print(pygame.mixer.get_init())
(22050, -16, 2)

>>> # the following will essentially be ignored
>>> pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2)
>>> print(pygame.mixer.get_init())
(22050, -16, 2)

>>> # calling quit() allows new parameters to be set
>>> pygame.mixer.quit()
>>> pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2)
>>> print(pygame.mixer.get_init())
(44100, -16, 2)
```